# Sluggish UI using SQLite

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I started developing a simple app in Flutter.
I use SQLite database to store some information and later show it on a ListView.Builder().

I pretty much do the same has [here](https://github.com/Rahiche/sqlite_demo/blob/master/lib/main.dart).
The problem is when i delete for instance a ListTile for a few frames I'm able to see the delete ListTile flashing before disappearing (I have implement a swipe do delete the ListTile).
I guess this happens because it takes time for it to update the database and get the new records and rebuild the ListView with the new info.

What can i do to solve this problem and make it more responsive? Any tips are welcome.

PS: I have started to look into the BLOC pattern. Not sure if it will help with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: post your code then

Comment: You might want to run the app in release mode, in debug mode the performance is poor and sometimes miss-leading.